# Calling the "no space" voice command with Dragon NaturallySpeaking from another voice command

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I wrote the following voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys"number_of_"
    Wait(0.2)
    HeardWord "no", "space"
End Sub
```

The point of the command is to type `number_of_`, then prevent Dragon from adding a space when the user dictate another word. As a result, I used `HeardWord` to call the `no space` voice command.

Everything works as expected except the line `HeardWord "no", "space"`, which fails to call the `no space` voice command. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `HeardWord`, you need to write the exact name of the command, and not some homonym. In this example, the exact name of the command is `No-Space`, and subsequently you should write:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys"number_of_"
    Wait(0.2)
    HeardWord "No-Space"
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Dragon do you use? I use DNS13 and the vocabulary entry for `underscore` (`_`) is already set to have no space preceding and following. So after the `SendKeys"number_of_"` line, without the next 2 lines, I get the next word being added with no preceding space. In general, I think this kind of thing is better handled with the vocabulary editor, anyway. So you could have a word with a spoken form of `special variable` with a written form of `numberof` and set the properties to have no following space and the next utterance will be added without the space `numberofthings`.

Comment: @PGilm thanks, good catch, I should indeed use this property of having no following space. (I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 pro). However, if I use a command, I do seem to need to add `HeardWord "No-Space"` otherwise it adds a space :/